# jQuery .click() function on submit - not sending value

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, submit

I have two simple submit buttons on my form, which work just fine:

```
<button id="accept" type="submit" name="accept" value="accept">Accept</button>
<button id="decline" type="submit" name="decline" value="decline">Decline</button>
```

However, the page in question you can either view by going directly to the URL, or it is occasionally displayed in a modal dialog, which I have setup using the following jQuery:

```
dialog.dialog({
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Decline", click: function() {
                $('#decline').click();
                dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Accept", click: function() {
                $('#accept').click();
                dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        }
    ]
});

dialog.load(url + '&ajax=1');
```

This submits the form just fine, and it detects all post information apart from the element that was actually clicked. So for example, if you load the form, and click the #decline button, that information will be posted, this isn't the case with jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful with dialogs as they don't make your submit action from your inputs wait. As soon as you click the submission is triggered.
You should use inputs of type button instead of submit and manage yourself the submission with the $(form).submit() method. It might solve your problems

EDIT: to answer your comment:

```
<style>
.submitbutton{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    /* you can do whatever you like here */
}​
</style>
<div id="dialog"></div>
<form id="myform">
<input id="accept" class="submitbutton" type="text" value="Accept button" name="accept" value="accept"/>
<input id="decline" class="submitbutton" type="text" value="Decline button" name="decline" value="decline"/>

</form>​
<script>
$('#accept,#decline').click(function(e){
    alert('you clicked #'+$(this).attr('id'));
    //you can do whatever you want here as you know which button was pressed.
    // to add more information in your form :
    $('#myform').append($("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "newhiddendata").val("something"));
    $('#myform').submit();
});

var dialog= $('#dialog');
dialog.dialog({
    modal:true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Decline", click: function() {
                dialog.dialog('close');
                $('#decline').click();

            }
        },
        {
            text: "Accept", click: function() {
                dialog.dialog('close');
                $('#accept').click();
            }
        }
    ]
});
​
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/KPu7G/

this is really raw, no css at all but you see the point.

Comment: Thank you, I did initially have the buttons as inputs but I had serious problems in IE8, also it meant I couldn't have icons/images next to each button! :-)

If I manage the submissions using $(form).submit() how will it know which button I pressed? Thanks again

Comment: Great answer. For various reasons (see the linked pages) it's preferred that rather than putting a link to code, you include the code in your answer. Here are some pages with further info: [Answer that only contains a link to jsFiddle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84342/166045) and a likely FAQ listing: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/166045)

Comment: Glad to help. I've learned a lot from the posts on the meta site ever since I stumbled onto it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden element to your form and when a button is clicked, have it set the value of that element before it submits the form.

Comment: Thank you, I'm thinking this could be the best option!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
dialog.dialog({
    buttons: {
            "Decline": function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Accept": function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }           
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but, um, how will the buttons submit the form? :)

Comment: Thanks, but then how would the form know which button was pressed?